# Angular 5 - HTTPClient Which side makes the calls?

Tags: angular

I have a very basic question regarding the Angular HTTPClient module.

I'm planning to have an Angular web front end publicly available, while I want the backend API to remain in private network.

If I use HTTPClient module in my Angular app, which side is going to execute these HTTP calls ? The client connecting publicly or the Web server hosting the Angular app ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client makes the HTTP calls, not the node.js server on which you are hosting your Angular app. You can check this by opening the Developer Tools (F12) in the browser that you use when using your client application. All HTTP calls made by the client will show up in the Network tab.

Comment: Thanks for your response, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPClient make call to server , correct ?, so when you make call to server , it going to execute at serverside , and you will get response at client side.

My mean to say

Client make Request to Server via HttpClient (creating request and sending done at client side in browser) >> server Process Request where its hosted and return response (this done in hosted server) >> Client receive response and process it at client end (i.e. in browser)

Please try to understand Client / Server architecture and you will understand easily.